# Check if two strings contain a similar substring

Tags: java, string

I am trying to write a program and part of that program is finding a similarity between two strings. You ask the user how many similar letters should be with in the strings.

For example:

```
string1 = aghilfamjijasrnlklk;
string2 = dfdfkkjhklkfnajnvfo;
```

user types 3,

program prints:

```
klk is similar in both 
starts at index 16, ends at 19 in string 1
starts at index 8, ends at 11 in string 2
```

What I have tried:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= search; i++) {
        if (string1.regionMatches(i, string2, 0, substringlength)) {
            found = true;
            System.out.print("Match found!");

            break;


        }
    }
```

I would have done more but I am at a complete stand still and do not know what to do; I am fairly new at coding.

Comment: Can we see what have you tried?

Comment: So far I have tried to use regionMatch, but that only works if they both begin with the same string.

Comment: You need to write an algorithm which will start in string 1 and get a n size (where n is the user input size eg. 3) substring starting from 0. Then search for that substring in string 2. Then move to position  1 in string 1 and repeat each time searching in string 2.

Comment: The question isn't clear; do you want to find substrings that are [similar but not identical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching)?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing the way to do this is to use the LCS algorithm (Longest Common subsequence) and at the end just take the first X amount of Chars the algorithm gives you. (ofcourse this isn't the most computational fastest but the algorithm is almost completely written by others)

As an example LCS(computer , uouthgr) will give you a string value of "outr" if the user wanted only 3 chars give him the subString of "out".

Here is the LCS code I found on the net (it need modifications to serve your purpose):

public class LCS {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String x = StdIn.readString();
    String y = StdIn.readString();
    int M = x.length();
    int N = y.length();

    // opt[i][j] = length of LCS of x[i..M] and y[j..N]
    int[][] opt = new int[M+1][N+1];

    // compute length of LCS and all subproblems via dynamic programming
    for (int i = M-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        for (int j = N-1; j >= 0; j--) {
            if (x.charAt(i) == y.charAt(j))
                opt[i][j] = opt[i+1][j+1] + 1;
            else 
                opt[i][j] = Math.max(opt[i+1][j], opt[i][j+1]);
        }
    }

    // recover LCS itself and print it to standard output
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    while(i < M && j < N) {
        if (x.charAt(i) == y.charAt(j)) {
            System.out.print(x.charAt(i));
            i++;
            j++;
        }
        else if (opt[i+1][j] >= opt[i][j+1]) i++;
        else                                 j++;
    }
    System.out.println();

}
```

}

for more detail I recommend to read:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem

but if you are like me I will recommend more to look for a video on the subject in youtube!